# Avoiding proliferation of templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am working on a fairly tightly coupled library which up until now has explicitly assumed all computations are done with doubles. I'm in the process of converting some of the core classes to templates so that we can start computing with `std::complex<double>`. I've templated about 10 of our classes so far have noticed a tendency toward proliferation of templates. As one class becomes templated, any other class that uses the templated class appears to need templating as well. I think I can avoid some of this proliferation by defining abstract base classes for my templates so that other classes can just use pointers to the abstract class and then refer to either a `double` or `std::complex<double>` version of the derived class. This seems to work on at the header level, but when I dive into the source files, the templated class will often have functions which compute a value or container of values of type `double` or `std::complex<double>`. It seems like a waste to template a whole class just because a couple of lines in the source file are different because of some other classes return type.

The use of `auto` seems like a possible way to fix this, but I'm not 100% sure it would work. Suppose I have an abstract base class `AbstractFunction` from which `Function<Scalar>` derives, where `Scalar` can be `double` or `std::complex<double>`. Now suppose we have two member functions:

```
virtual Scalar Function<Scalar>::value(double x);
virtual void Function<Scalar>::values(std::vector<Scalar> &values, std::vector<double> x);
```

And suppose I have some other class (that I don't want to template) with a member function that calls one of these.

```
// populate double x and std::vector<double> xs
auto value = functionPtr->value(x);
std::vector<auto> values;
functionPtr->values(values, xs);
// do something with value and values
```

where `functionPtr` is of type `std::shared_ptr<AbstractFunction>`.
I could see `auto` working for the first case, but I don't believe I could construct a vector of `auto` to be filled with the second one. Does this necessitate making the calling class a template? Can someone recommend another strategy to cut down on the proliferation of templates?

Comment: is `AbstractFunction` in your example also a template? should the methods `value()` and `values()` be pure virtual within `AbstractFunction`? you should give a more detailed example.

Comment: AbstractFunction is not a template in order to give a common ancestor for Function<double> and Function<std::complex<double>>. I realize my example may be a little flawed since the `value()` and `values()` functions depend on the template parameter, they probably can't exist within `AbstractFunction` even as pure virtual functions.

Comment: "It seems a bit of a waste" -- what _exactly_ is your goal here? Is, for example, "decreasing the size of the executable for programs that use both versions of the function" actually something that matters? It sort of sounds like you're avoiding templates just for the sake of avoiding templates, rather than having an actual, concrete goal in mind.

Comment: I guess it was getting to the point where I had to fully template a class that didn't seem like it was directly involved in our goal of supporting `std::complex` just because it had one reference to a class that was already templated. I don't know if there was anything wrong with that, it just felt like there had to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are already wrong in assuming that the first use-case is going to work. If you have an abstract base class, then either `value` is a member of it and you can call it through `std::shared_ptr<AbstractFunction>` or `value` is not a member of it and only available if you know the derived class' type. In the first case, the `AbstractFunction::value` method must have a fixed return type, it can not depend on `Scalar`, which is the template parameter of the derived class.

That said: In my experience the two concept often don't mix well. You either want to create an abstract base class with the full interface or you want a template. In the latter case, there is often no need / no benefit for having an abstract base class. It then follows that also the code using your template works with templates.

What might help you is to "export" the template parameter from `Function`, i.e.

```
template<typename T>
class Function
{
public:
    using value_type = T;
    value_type value() const;
    // ...
};
```

and in other parts of the code, use a template which takes any `T` which behaves like `Function` if you don't want to directly write out (and limit yourself) to `Function`:

```
template<typename T>
void something( const std::shared_ptr<T>& functionPtr )
{
   // ignoring where x comes from...
   using V = typename T::value_type;
   V value = functionPtr->value(x);
   std::vector<V> values;
   functionPtr->values(values, xs);
}
```

Note that this is just one option, I don't know if it is the best option for your use-case.

Comment: I think you are right. As I chase this abstract base class idea further down the rabbit hole, it seems less and less like a viable solution. It just seems like by the time I am done, every class in our library is going to end up templated.